# Why are these high fee transactions not being mined?

Tags: mining, gas, etherscan, gas-price

Looking at the state of pending transactions on [Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/txsPending?ps=50&sort=gasprice&order=desc&m=) I noticed two transactions that have a gas price much higher than that of the average network fee, yet they are not being mined.
The transaction belong to the following [Account](https://etherscan.io/address/0xd6cf7f63c4a5f2c839f060e3ae0da477c856ef84)

At the time of writing, the asking gas price  is ~40GWei, these two transactions offer 220GWei and 550Gwei respectively. Yet they are pending for about an hour.

Is there a reason for a miner not to include these transactions? The address seems quite "fresh" so censorship does not make sense. Is this a bug of Etherscan?
It is also strange that both transactions have the same nonce (1)

[image: Pending transactions of an account]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Sender doesn't have enough ether to pay fees+value

Comment: @ismael, in this case, wouldn't they be executed anyway and only the fee deducted? There is enough balance to cover the fee.

Comment: No, if you can't pay in advance value+tx fees the transaction remains in pending pool.

Comment: That makes sense. In this case wasn't the transaction supposed to dropped by the node broadcasting it? Is there something special about it that it managed to reach Etherscan?

Comment: It is still a valid transaction so nodes are allowed to broadcast it. Eventually it might be dropped from pending pool, but anyone can re-broadcast it again if it wasn't replaced.